# Cannot submit tag wiki edits

Tags: support, tagging, community-wiki

I've been adding a few tag wikis to the database but all of a sudden am facing an error message whenever I try to submit a new one. It says something to the effect of "There was an error submitting this post." If I wait a bit and try again I get the "You must wait 30 seconds to perform this action" message, but once I wait the indicated time it gives me the first error again. I've restarted the browser in case it was a cache issue and have tried multiple tags but get the same results each time. I've seen this error before but usually it goes away within a minute and I can continue editing for a while before it happens again, but now it's constant and I can't get anything done.

Did I fill up a log or a queue somewhere?

Comment: Could very well be the queue filling up (it is 48 tags to be approved right now). I do not have the time right now to check and approve them, but hang in their and hopefully you will be able to continue your hard work soon!

Comment: Oh yeah that's probably my fault... I've been watching progress bars all day and tag editing was my entertainment >.<

Comment: Hehe nothing like a good tag editing on a slow Friday ;)

Comment: We have approved some more now, give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks! One of these days I'll have the privilege to work that queue myself so it won't pile up on everyone else (:

Comment: @thanby Until you have 20k rep, you can't edit tags wikis without them being reviewed by others. On questions and answer you need only 2k to edit posts without review, and with this pace, you'll be there in six days :-)

Comment: Ah I didn't realize tag wikis were a separate queue, figured they were in suggested edits. Hopefully you folks won't get sick of seeing my name everywhere for a little while! By the time I'm done I intend to give every tag a meaningful definition. Is there a way to flag ones that are incorrect or irrelevant?

Comment: @thanby Not a chance. You're doing a fantastic job - so please continue